# python kivy AnchorLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class root(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()


#:kivy 1.10.1

<root>:
    size_hint: None, None

    Label:
        id: player1_name
        anchor_x: "left"
        anchor_y: "top"
        text: "First Player"

    Label:
        id: player2_name
        anchor_x: "left"
        anchor_y: "top"
        text: "Second Player"
```

В общем anchor_x и anchor_y не срабатывают, надписи все в левом углу. Можно сделать это как - то в .kv файле, не прибегая к вложенным виджетам через .add_widget? Очень громоздко получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понял, Вам нужен следующий вид окна:

- верхняя левая четверть занята текстом First Player
- верхняя правая четверть - текстом Second Player

В таком случае структура kv может выглядеть так:

```
FloatLayout

    AnchorLayout

        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'

        Label
            size_hint: .5,.5
            text: "First Player"

    AnchorLayout

        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'

        Label
            size_hint: .5,.5
            text: "Second Player"
```

Таким образом:

1. root будет Float лейаутом, а в нем - два Anchor лейаута, и в каждом
   из них по лейблу.
2. anchor_x и anchor_y относятся к Anchor лейауту, поэтому пишутся именно в нем, а не в дочерних виджетах.
3. size_hint в данном случае означает, какую долю будет занимать каждый Label внутри своего Anchor Layout'а.
   Оба Anchor лейаута здесь являются дочерними для Float лейаута, поэтому занимают все пространство окна.

Вариант исправленного кода:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

app.kv:

```
<root>:

    AnchorLayout

        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'

        Label:
            id: player1_name
            size_hint: .5,.5
            text: "First Player"

    AnchorLayout

        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'

        Label:
            id: player2_name
            size_hint: .5,.5
            text: "Second Player"
```